# elasticsearch search - search multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I am new to elastic search and I am trying to search my index that has the following properties:

```js
// user index
{
  profile: {
    name: string,
    description: string,
    city: string
    state: string
  },
  services: [
    {
      serviceName: string
    },
    {
      serviceName: string
    },
    {
      serviceName: string
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I am trying to combine my `query_string` and `nested`, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```js
body: {
  query: {
    query_string: {
      query: `*${searchTerm}*`,
      fields: [
        // these profile fields work
        'profile.name',
        'profile.description',
        'profile.city',
        'profile.state',

        // doesnt work, need to use nested
        'services.serviceName'
      ]
    },

    // if i use nested here, elasticsearch throws error
    // can I combine these two queries like this?
    nested: {

    }
  }
}
```

I cannot find any good examples to have both a `nested` AND `query_string` search query.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Anything helps, even links to good docs / examples for the thing I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `query_string` and [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html), using the boolean query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "search term",
              "fields": []
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "services",
              "query": {
                "services.serviceName": "blue"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ESCoder, is there any IRC or chatroom for elastic search?

Comment: I am getting `[parsing_exception] Reason: unknown query [query]`

Comment: Ok, I had to remove the extra `"query"` parent of the `"query_string"` and `"nested"` keys

Comment: @Zac its been a long time ! Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue. TIA ;-)